# supervisorctl wont start or recognize new flask app run via nginx

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I added a file in nginx(`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/va`) , which contains:

```
server {
   server_name va.com;
   listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/va/static/;
    }
}
```

For **flask**, I added a new config(`/home/www/flask-deploy/config/va`):

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/va/static/;
    }
}
```

Theres another file in this same directory called: `va.conf` which contains:

```
[program:va]
command = gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8001
directory = /home/www/flask-deploy/va
user = jd
```

However, which I try the following `supervisorctl` commands to see the changes in `supervisor`:
`service supervisor stop`
`service supervisor start`
`supervisorctl reread`

If I then try to start up this `va` supervisor process via:
`supervisorctl start va` **it fails with**:
`va: ERROR (no such process)`

If I try: `supervisorctl status` it **outputs**:

```
flask_blog                       STARTING   
flask_project                    RUNNING    pid 8890, uptime 0:12:50]
```

but no mention of the new `va` config.

What am I possibly doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Did you run supervisorctl reload and where is your conf file located?

Comment: @Boris - yes I did it then stated "Restarted supervisord". the va and va.conf are located in `/home/www/flask-deploy/config` where the original configs are too (which are working)

Comment: I was about to ask you if you checked the /etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf to make sure that va app conf file is in the right directory, but you already did that. If your va.conf is in the same dir with other app files then maybe check the supervisor log. It should give you some clues.

Comment: @Boris - now nginx wont restart. I shut it down, then tried to start it back up, and it fails to start leading to more problems. can you help in a chat?

Comment: Not sure if you resolved the issue, but I have some free time now, if you are still interested.